# Outlook: How to automatically copy all received messages to another folder and mark as Unread

Tags: vba, outlook

I have tried to find a script or rule which will let me copy all inbound messages to an archive folder and then mark the mail as unread.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, or help with a script please?

I can find plenty that will mark as read, but not as unread.

Thanks in advance, Neil

Answer (score 0):

An outlook [`MailItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861252(v=office.14).aspx) object has a property [`UnRead`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868556(v=office.14).aspx) which you can toggle as boolean, either `True` (unread) or `False` (read).

> Returns or sets a Boolean value that is `True` if the Outlook item has not been opened (read). Read/write.

Comment: @Michael, thanks, for the reply and the welcome.  What you describe is exactly what I have now, except, I have since imported c. 50GB of mail, and would like to mark it as unread as well.  I can't see a way to do that through rules, unless you can tell me where I've missed it?

Comment: I'm not Michael. You should probably comment on his answer, if you want to get his attention.  Also, your Q probably needs some clarification, as it mentions "inbound" messages (presumably *received* messages), but your comment now indicates that you're importing 50GB of messages from somewhere else.

Comment: Apologies David, I replied to the wrong response.  I have imported mail, and it is the imported mail I would like to set as unread.  The rule, as you correctly stated, is working as expected.  So, to clarify, I would like a script or rule that would mark everything in a folder as unread.  The script I have just doesn't seem to work; it doesn't error, just nothing appears to happen.  Am I allowed to post the script here?

Answer (score 0):

and welcome to StackOverflow!

To achieve the result that you are looking for, it would be a simple Outlook Rule. Assuming that you are using Outlook 2013, you would just need to go to your Inbox, the select under the Home tab, **Rules**. Then create a new rule. Start from a blank rule with messages that you receive. Then click next. (Outlook will ask you whether you are sure if you want the rule to run on every email message, click yes) Then chack the box that states, **"move a copy to the specified folder"**. That folder will be your archive. Then, if you would like to, you can choose whether you want a desktop alert for the email. There is no need to select an option of having the email unread, because the email by default is unread when copied to the archive.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yaschuk, thanks, for the reply and the welcome.  What you describe is exactly what I have now, except, I have since imported c. 50GB of mail, and would like to mark it as unread as well.  I can't see a way to do that through rules, unless you can tell me where I've missed it?

Comment: Thanks, but right-click and mark as unread isn't an option, and Ctrl A and Mark As Unread seems to hang with 250k messages.

Answer (score 0):

As  workaround you can create rule based on email size (with a size in a specific range). You can put 0 to 999999 and then move a copy to any folder. This should copy all your inbox emails to another folder.